# how do I change the settings of an actuator(python)

Tags: python, game-engine

I want to change the time of a object that is added but I am new to python and don't know how to. I am trying to create randomly lasting smoke trails.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be familiar with Python already, you might wanna look into the [time property for the actuator in the API](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.types.KX_SCA_AddObjectActuator.html#bge.types.KX_SCA_AddObjectActuator). Alternatively, you could just use the [addObject](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.types.KX_Scene.html?highlight=addobject#bge.types.KX_Scene.addObject) method. If I am right it does the same thing but saves you one element in the Logic Bricks.